# Give notification for disabled button in Android

Tags: android, button, developer-tools

What to do to give a notification in android app, when user tries to click on the button which is currently disabled ? It will be enabled in future. Then it has to perform another operation. 
Help me with the disabled case ...

Comment: @harvey_slash are you sure about that?

Comment: @harvey_slash let me check that......

Comment: @harvey_slash please post the answer

Comment: @harvey_slash please post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using **onTouchListener**. AFAIK,setEnabled(false) disables onClick, but it should leave the onTouchListener working. Just remember one thing, **return false from the listener** once your work is done(in order to consume the event allow other events after it to be fired)

Answer (score 0):

I would overlay it with a transparent view, and add an `OnClickListener` to the transparent view.

At least this way you are using a pattern you are familiar with, and it will be easier when you update the app in the future.

Answer (score 0):

once you disabled that button you can no longer perform or get any kind of listeners on that disabled button. So i suggest you use the following method

you will be having a specific condition to disable the button lets say that condition is "disCondition"

```
 disCondition = true//button disabled

 button onClick(){
 if(disCondition){
  //Show toast message
  //and change the button background to disabled image
 }else{
  //perform the normal button click 
 }
}
```

now change the button background according to the disCondition.